# Intercepting output to STDERR

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby application which- unexpectedly - from time to time outputs a lone line feed character to stderr. I would like to find the place in my program where this happens. Static analysis (grepping case-insensitively for *stderr*) did not reveal anything useful, i.e. while there were some `STDERR.puts` statements, they always output also something else besides the \n, so they can't be the culprit.

Does anybody have some idea how I can somehow catch every write to stderr, and if it happens, at least print a backtrace, so that I can see where this write originates?

Comment: You can rewrap `$stderr` as something else to catch writes to it, or reassign the `STDERR` const depending on which is used.

Comment: I already thought about opening the object as `class << $stderr`, and redefining suitable methods by printing the stack to stdout and then calling `super`, but even  then, the question is _which_ methods to redefine. The same problem would occur when writing a wrapper around `$stderr`. Since I don't know, how the output is produce, I don't know which method to catch (i.e. `puts`, ....).

Comment: That's why replacing it with a super-explodey object with `method_missing(name, *args)` defined as `raise 'nope'` could help. It'll burst into flames when anything tries any methods on STDERR. You may have to implement stubs for others that are just checking if it's open, etc.

Comment: @tadmann : Did not think about `method_missing`! If you turn the comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trap all calls to a particular object there's a lot of utility in `method_missing`:

```
class Exploder
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    raise "Method #{name} was called!"
  end
end
```

You can then substitute it and trap calls:

```
$stderr = Exploder.new
```

Any call like `$stderr.write` will now raise an exception.